# Camel Multicast behaving strangely

Tags: apache-camel

I am getting as strange behavior from Camel Multicast. Looks like I am doing something wrong but can't point it.

I am creating a multicast route to two endpoints as below:

```
Start point : direct://start
endpoint : direct://route1
endpoint : direct://route2
```

Routes info :

1) `from("direct://start").process(new DeepCloneRequest()).multicast(new Aggregator()).to("direct://route1","direct://route2")`

2) `from("direct://route1").setheader(<to use later in processor>).process(<do some preprocessing>).to("rest url1").processor(<to do post processing>).end`

3) `from("direct://route2").setheader(<to use later in processor>).process(<do some preprocessing>).to("rest url2").processor(<to do post processing>).end`

What I notice is that in my route number 3 in preprocessing I got the exchange out of number 2 preprocessing instead of DeepCloneRequest from multicast.

Can someone please help explain this? I want to get same request that multicast receive in both route 2 and 3.

The Camel version I am using is 2.17.3.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the onPrepare feature, see http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html

"The Multicast will copy the source Exchange and multicast each copy. However the copy is a shallow copy, so in case you have **mutateable message bodies**, then any **changes will be visible by the other copied messages**. If you want to use a deep clone copy then you need to use a custom onPrepare which allows you to do this using the Processor interface."